# Using and compiling cvlink blockset

Tags: opencv, simulink

Some info about cvlink:

cvLink is an efficient and free computer vision blockset for simulink. cvLink is developed on openCV library, a great computer vision opensource project.

The library has >60 optimized blocks. It runs about three times faster than the official video and image processing blockset of Mathworks and enables (soft) real time vision up to 60 frames per second under Simulink.

---

I downloaded cvlink, and followed the instructions of this website http://www.lab.cnrs.fr/openblockslib/cvLink.html

When i tried to run a demo in simulink, i got an error in every s-function, it says that s-function doesn't exists. I thought that i should recompile cvlink, so again i followed website's instructions in order to compile it.
I configured Visual C++ and type mex-setup, aparently at least it worked well. So I type cvbuildall in matlab and got:

Version of matlab 7.7, opencv 2.2, cvlink 1.2b

```
 >> cvbuildall
*** Building  cvLinkArithmeticOperation  library ***
Building  cvabsdiff.cpp...
Creating  library  C:\USERS\MRMEAN\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\MEX_BF~1\templib.x and object     
 C:\USERS\MRMEAN\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\MEX_BF~1\templib.exp 

 cvabsdiff.obj  :  error  LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvAbsDiff referenced in function "void     __cdecl mdlOutputs(struct SimStruct_tag *,int)" (?mdlOutputs@@YAXPEAUSimStruct_tag@@H@Z) 

 cvabsdiff.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvResetImageROI referenced in function "void    __cdecl mdlOutputs(struct SimStruct_tag *,int)" (?mdlOutputs@@YAXPEAUSimStruct_tag@@H@Z) 

cvabsdiff.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvSetImageROI referenced in   function "void __cdecl mdlOutputs(struct SimStruct_tag *,int)" (?mdlOutputs@@YAXPEAUSimStruct_tag@@H@Z) 

cvabsdiff.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvGetImageROI referenced in function "void __cdecl mdlOutputs(struct SimStruct_tag *,int)" (?mdlOutputs@@YAXPEAUSimStruct_tag@@H@Z) 

 cvabsdiff.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvCloneImage referenced in function "void __cdecl mdlOutputs(struct SimStruct_tag *,int)" (?mdlOutputs@@YAXPEAUSimStruct_tag@@H@Z) 

 cvabsdiff.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvReleaseImage referenced in function "void __cdecl mdlTerminate(struct SimStruct_tag *)" (?mdlTerminate@@YAXPEAUSimStruct_tag@@@Z) 

 cvinterface.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvSetErrStatus referenced in function "int __cdecl cvLinkErr(int,char const *,char const *,char const *,int,void *)" (?cvLinkErr@@YAHHPEBD00HPEAX@Z) 

 cvabsdiff.mexw64 : fatal error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals 

 C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2008B\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Link of 'cvabsdiff.mexw64' failed. 

??? Error using ==> mex at 213
Unable to complete successfully.

Error in ==> cvbuild at 25
eval(P);
Error in ==> cvbuildall at 7
cvbuild cvabsdiff.cpp
```

---

I tried to modify cvbuild but it didn't worked.

Any suggestion? thanks in advance.